# Effects of electroplating soft magnetic materials

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, material-science, magnetic-moment, molecular-dynamics

Considering how electroplating adheres molecules and compounds on a molecular basis, how would electroplating a soft magnetic material, such as an electromagnet, with diamagnetic atoms, like bismuth, behave when a magnetic field is activated once the diamagnetic material is applied? How would the coating behave?